# adding days with a date in php

Tags: php

In my project i have to get the expiry date of a package from the 'date of purchasing' the package and the 'validity in days' of the package.I got a code from the php.net as follows

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Now suppose the date of purchase is like
  2013-01-17
and the validity in days is
    180
Now if i use the php.net example as follows

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-17');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P180D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Will i get the output as 2013-04-17?
I need the output like

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I cant run the program in my personal computer but i have to carry on the codding of the project so i'm here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime('2013-01-17');
 $date->add(new DateInterval('P180D'));
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>

//output
//2013-07-16   and it is in yyyy-mm-dd format
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/gAtT2D

and if you can't run the program in your PC, use online debugger shell.

Comment: thanks fro codepad viper link...i was trying in codepad.org but there was a fatal error for my code